# How get cart content ? (prestashop)

Tags: cart, prestashop

I'd like get cart content on prestashop os-commerce. How can do it ?

Comment: Take a look at the blockcart module, it will give you an idea of how to do it

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the Cart class, located in classes/Cart.php. There's a method called getProducts().

```php
/**  
 * Return cart products  
 *  
 * @result array Products  
 */  
 public function getProducts($refresh = false, $id_product = false)  
 {  
   // code...  
 }
```

Hope this helps,

Br,

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
Context::getContext()->cart
```

refer this link 
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/440516-how-to-get-all-product-ids-in-current-cart/

Answer (score 0):

It's Working: Enjoy

in module hook you can use this:

```
$products = $params['cart']->getProducts(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a hook on Shopping Cart page you can use:

```
$products = $params['products'];
```

Answer (score 0):

in .tpl file you can use `cart` object advantage and loop through products:

```php
{foreach from=$cart->getProducts() item=product}
    {$product.name}
{/foreach}
```